# Why is this login CSRF verification failing? I'm able to get the key

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, csrf-token

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import lxml

# Page header
head= { 'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36'
}
# Start Page
url = 'https://www.rewardstyle.com'
# Login URL
login_url = 'https://auth.rewardstyle.com/login/'
# URL behind the login page
url2= 'https://www.rewardstyle.com/products/recent?lang=en_US'


# Open up a session
s = requests.session()

# Open the login page
r = s.get(login_url)
# Retrieve the CSRF token first
csrftoken = s.cookies['csrftoken']
print(csrftoken)
```

This prints a csrf token, although my error may be that its not valid?
Next I post the data, but no luck:

```
# Get the page cookie
cookies = r.cookies

# Set CSRF-Token
head['X-CSRF-Token'] = csrftoken
head['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest'

payload = {
'username':'myuser',
'password':'mypassword',
}

r = requests.post(login_url, data=payload, headers = head)
print(r.content)
```

i include a valid user and password my error is:

> ## Forbidden (403)
>
> CSRF verification failed.
> Request aborted.
>
> You are seeing this message because
> this site requires a CSRF cookie when submitting forms. This cookie is
> required for security reasons

Answer (score 0):

This works for anyone wondering.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import lxml

# Page header
head= { 'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36'
}
# Start Page
url = 'https://www.rewardstyle.com'
# Login URL
login_url = 'https://auth.rewardstyle.com/login/'
# URL behind the login page
url2= 'https://www.rewardstyle.com/products/recent?lang=en_US'


# Open up a session
s = requests.session()

# Open the login page
r = s.get(login_url)
# Retrieve the CSRF token first
csrftoken = s.cookies['csrftoken']
print(csrftoken) #Check if it's getting printed. Sometimes key name could be 'csrf' only

# Get the page cookie
cookies = r.cookies

# Set CSRF-Token
head['X-CSRF-Token'] = csrftoken
head['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest'
head['Referer'] = login_url

payload = {
'username':'username',
'password':'password',
'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : csrftoken,
}

r = s.post(login_url, data=payload, headers = head)
print(r.content)

# Try to get a page behind the login page
r = s.get(url2)

# Check if login was successful
print(r.content)
```